# Setting values at runtime doesn't work in multiplayer

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have 2 players, and I have 2 player models.

Now I want to set it so you can select which model you want.

So I made a button, and when you press it, and you press host/connect in the player's start, it runs this

```c#
if (!GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ButtonScript>().Buttonn)
{
    IsEye = false;
}

if (IsEye) {
    RobotParent.SetActive(false);
    EyeParent.SetActive(true);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center = new Vector3(0, 2.99f, 0.06880748f);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size = new Vector3(6.42f, 9.2f, 5.52f);
    anim = EyeParent.GetComponent<Animator>();
}

if (!IsEye)
{
    RobotParent.SetActive(true);
    EyeParent.SetActive(false);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center = new Vector3(0, 0.1912432f, 0.06880748f);
    gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size = new Vector3(0.812993f, 3.379633f, 1.02866f);
    //anim = EyeParent.GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

This checks if the button is pressed, and if it is pressed, then enables the eye model.

But when the second player connects, on Players 2's screen, if they chose the first model, everyone is the first model, but if they chose the second model, everyone is the second model.

And the same thing happens on the first players screen, if they choose the first model, everyone is the first model, and if they choose the second model, everyone is the second model.

Hopefully you understand my problem, if you need more information, just tell me

Comment: GameObject. FindObjectOfType finds the first active object of the Type - ButtonScript. Is it possible this is causing the state to change for all players as soon as the new player joins?

Comment: Maybe, but that change only happens one the second player's screen, on the first players screen, the second player has the same model as the first player, and on the second player's screen, the first player has the same model as the second player.

Comment: This is because you haven't networked the activity. The buttonpress is a local event and the corresponding change also.

Comment: How do i do that?, sorry i am new to networking. @HeadhunterXamd

Comment: Depends on the networking framework you are using. The most basic principle is that you need to network the event as a message to the clients, who then need to do some functions based on what the message tells them to.

Comment: I am using unity3D UNET, can you atleast provide some code, so i know where to start?

Comment: this link: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=Network with this:https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetMessages.html
giving more explanation in how to send the messages.

Comment: First you should complete [Unity - Introduction Simple Multiplayer-Example](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/?pintroduction-simple-multiplayer-example). Than you have to [differ between the players](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/identifying-local-player?playlist=29690) `if(isLocalPlayer)`. Than you have to [syncronize the choice](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/networking-player-movement?playlist=29690) of each Player. You might want store them in a proper class on the server.